# How to change the tint color for Navigation Bar Buttons for Sharing Mail App composer

Tags: ios, swift

In my app we are showing native sharing option to the user to share a file. In that when we're choosing Mail App option then its presenting Mail App Composer controller. So here my issue is I want to change Navigation Bar Buttons tint color (Send and Cancel). But I am unable to change the color of these bar buttons.

So is there is a way to change the colors of these buttons. I tried this code:

```
myController.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.white
```

Here is the scrrenshot for better understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in your `viewDidLoad`:

```
UIBarButtonItem.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UINavigationBar.self]).tintColor = UIColor.white
```

Answer (score 0):

So the reason why it is not working is because it is not your view controller you are trying to change the navigation item's color, it is the 
MFMailComposeViewController.

What you could try is the following:

```
let composeVC = MFMailComposeViewController()
composeVC.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = .white
```

If it is not as simple as changing the tintColor like that, you may have to do a bit more work and actually make custom class that subclasses MFMailComposeViewController in order to change the tint color for the navigation bar items.